# Grab information from a php script and display on a winform

Tags: c#, php, winforms

I have a php script that returns a list of file directories held at the root of a remote server that I need to display in my winform application. For example if I put the link in my browser it returns something like the following:

> 511157.jpg|Koala.jpg|VIDEO0031.3gp|Test_Folder.folder

However, I have never accessed a php script through a C# application before and nor have I displayed the information it may hold.

Is there a best practice for being able to connect and grab the information via a php script? 
Could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    String result = client.DownloadString("www.foosite.com/page.php");
}
```